# ¿Como llenar una table layout con mysql en android studio?

Tags: android-studio

Hola amigos del foro esperando que todos se encuentren muy bien de salud, siguiendo con el tema del tablelayout, ya me funciona el ingresar datos a una tablelayout, el cual era ¿Problemas al ingresar datos en un tablelayout? que fue formulada el día de ayer y ya solucionada, pero lo que quiero ahora es lo siguiente que es llenar la misma tablelayout con los datos ya ingresado en mysql, este es lo que llevo realizado a la fecha.

```
public void mostrardatos (){
    String url = "http://192.*.*.*/oficina/buscar_vehiculos.php";
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            try {
                JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("");
                for (int i = 1; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
                    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
LayoutInflater registro = getLayoutInflater();
                    registro = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.tabla2,null,false);
                    
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

en el ciclo for del mostrar datos, se encuentra el Layoutinflater y en la senetancia this, me arroja el siguiente mensaje de error: "'from(android.content.Context)' in 'android.view.LayoutInflater' cannot be applied to '(anonymous com.android.volley.Response.Listener<org.json.JSONObject>)'", no se porque ahora, me sale este error, si anteriormente lo utilizo siempre así.
posteriormente creo que se debe utilizar un arreglo para que me muestre los datos en la tablelayout, pero ahí es donde tengo la duda.
Favor de asesorarme y desde ya muchas gracias.

---

Maestro te ingreso detalladamente el formulario completo con sus códigos respectivo, mis disculpas de antemano:
este es el main activity completo:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonArrayRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
```

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
EditText et_filas, et_tipo, et_marca, et_modelo;
Button ingresar, modificar;
TableLayout tbldatos;
private String[]header={"N° Filas","Tipo","Marca","Modelo"};
private ArrayList<String[]> rows=new ArrayList<>();
private TableDynamic tableDynamic;
RequestQueue requestQueue;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    et_filas = findViewById(R.id.txtitem);
    et_tipo = findViewById(R.id.txttipo);
    et_marca = findViewById(R.id.txtmarca);
    et_modelo = findViewById(R.id.txtmodelo);
    ingresar = findViewById(R.id.cmdingresar);
    modificar = findViewById(R.id.cmdmodificar);
    tbldatos = findViewById(R.id.tbldatos);

    tableDynamic = new TableDynamic(tbldatos, getApplicationContext());
    tableDynamic.addHeader(header);
    tableDynamic.addData(getClients());
    tableDynamic.backgroundHeader(Color.BLUE);
    tableDynamic.backgroundData(Color.RED, Color.YELLOW);
    tableDynamic.lineColor(Color.BLACK);
    tableDynamic.textColorData(Color.WHITE);
    tableDynamic.textColorHeader(Color.MAGENTA);
    mostrardatos();
}

private ArrayList<String[]> getClients(){

    return rows;
}

public void datos (View view){
    String[]item = new String[]{et_filas.getText().toString(),et_tipo.getText().toString(),et_marca.getText().toString(),et_modelo.getText().toString()};
    tableDynamic.addItems(item);
}

public void mostrardatos (){
    String url = "http://192.*.*.*/oficina/buscar_vehiculos.php";
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            try {
                JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("");
                for (int i = 1; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
                    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    **LayoutInflater registro = getLayoutInflater();
                    registro = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.tabla2,null,false);**
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
}
```

}

este es la clase con la que trabajo:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class TableDynamic {
private TableLayout tableLayout;
private Context context;
private String[] header;
private ArrayList<String[]> data;
private TableRow tableRow;
private TextView txtCell;
private int indexC;
private int indexR;
private boolean multiColor = false;
int firtColor, secondColor, textColor, colorLinea;

public TableDynamic(TableLayout tableLayout, Context context) {
    this.tableLayout = tableLayout;
    this.context = context;
}

public void addHeader(String[] header) {
    this.header = header;
    createHeader();
}

public void addData(ArrayList<String[]> data) {
    this.data = data;
    createDataTable();
}

private void newRow() {
    tableRow = new TableRow(context);
}

private void newCell() {
    txtCell = new TextView(context);
    txtCell.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    txtCell.setTextSize(18);
}

private void createHeader() {
    indexC = 0;
    newRow();
    while (indexC < header.length) {
        newCell();
        txtCell.setText(header[indexC++]);
        tableRow.addView(txtCell, newTableRowParams());
    }
    tableLayout.addView(tableRow);
}

private void createDataTable() {
    String info;
    for(indexR=1;indexR<= data.size();indexR++) {
        newRow();
        for(indexC=0;indexC<header.length;indexC++) {
            newCell();
            String[] row = data.get(indexR-1);
            info = (indexC<row.length)?row[indexC]:"";
            txtCell.setText(info);
            tableRow.addView(txtCell,newTableRowParams());
        }
        tableLayout.addView(tableRow);
    }
}

public void addItems(String[] item) {
    String info;
    data.add(item);
    indexC = 0;
    newRow();
    while (indexC < header.length) {
        newCell();
        info = (indexC < item.length) ? item[indexC++] : "";
        txtCell.setText(info);
        tableRow.addView(txtCell, newTableRowParams());
    }
    tableLayout.addView(tableRow, data.size());//Se quito el -1 despues de size para corregir
    reColoring();
    reColoringLinea();
}

public void backgroundHeader(int color) {
    indexC = 0;
    newRow();
    while (indexC < header.length) {
        txtCell = getCell(0, indexC++);
        txtCell.setBackgroundColor(color);
    }
}

public void backgroundData(int firtColor, int secondColor) {
    for (indexR = 1; indexR <= data.size(); indexR++) {
        multiColor = !multiColor;
        for (indexC = 0; indexC < header.length; indexC++) {
            txtCell = getCell(indexR, indexC);
            txtCell.setBackgroundColor((multiColor) ? firtColor : secondColor);
        }
    }
    this.firtColor = firtColor;
    this.secondColor = secondColor;
}

public void lineColor(int color) {
    indexR = 0;
    while (indexR <= data.size()) {
        getRow(indexR++).setBackgroundColor(color);
    }
    this.colorLinea = color;
}

public void textColorData(int color) {
    for (indexR = 1; indexR <= data.size(); indexR++) {
        for (indexC = 0; indexC < header.length; indexC++) {
            getCell(indexR, indexC).setTextColor(color);
        }
    }
    this.textColor = color;
}

public void textColorHeader(int color) {
    indexC = 0;
    while (indexC < header.length) {
        getCell(0, indexC++).setTextColor(color);
    }
}

public void reColoring() {
    indexC = 0;
    multiColor=!multiColor;
    while (indexC < header.length) {
        txtCell = getCell(data.size(), indexC++);
        txtCell.setBackgroundColor((multiColor) ? firtColor : secondColor);
        txtCell.setTextColor(textColor);
    }
}

public void reColoringLinea(){
    indexR = 0;
    while (indexR <= data.size()) {
        getRow(indexR++).setBackgroundColor(colorLinea);
    }
}

private TableRow getRow(int index) {
    return (TableRow) tableLayout.getChildAt(index);
}

private TextView getCell(int rowIndex, int columIndex) {
    tableRow = getRow(rowIndex);
    return (TextView) tableRow.getChildAt(columIndex);
}

private TableRow.LayoutParams newTableRowParams() {
    TableRow.LayoutParams params = new TableRow.LayoutParams();
    params.setMargins(1, 1, 1, 1);
    params.weight = 1;
    return params;
}
```

}

ojala que me puedan ayudar como poder mostrar todos los datos de la tabla que poseo en mysql actualmente poseo 6 registros (filas), y estos mismos mostrarlos en la tablelayout al momento de ingresar a la pantalla, eso es lo que pretendo y desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿A qué tabla te refieres? ¿Dónde la declaras en tu código? ¿De qué modo, según lo que has investigado, crees que debería llenarse?

Comment: A. Cedano te agregue el día de ayer de acuerdo a lo solicitado, estuve probando algunas ideas pero siempre me envían error de trafico de datos, y el json realizado se encuentra funcionando bien, ya que anteriormente lo probé con postman, desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: No hay que usar el área de respuestas para agregar detalles de la pregunta, pulsa en [edit] y agrégalos en la misma pregunta. Algo MUY IMPORTANTE es que cuando haya errores agregues también el mensaje completo del error, preferiblemente en forma de texto, no de capturas de imagen.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tus comentarios, soy nuevo en esta pagina y no conozco muy bien el reglamento que tienen, así que mis disculpas de antemano.

Comment: Además cambie un poco el código del main activity, y lo deje marcado en negro que me marca un error, en el this, "'from(android.content.Context)' in 'android.view.LayoutInflater' cannot be applied to '(anonymous com.android.volley.Response.Listener<org.json.JSONObject>)'", siempre lo hago así y ahora no se porque me envía este error, favor de asesorarme y desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: En mi comentario anterior te sugerí que pusieras todo en el área de preguntas y que agregaras el mensaje de error completo. No has hecho ni una cosa ni otra. Por favor completa la pregunta agregando todo en el área correspondiente para poder analizar el problema. Gracias.